# Comments in layout XML not working

Tags: android

yes, I looked it up!

```
<!-- comment -->
```

seems to be the right choice, 
but I get an error in android-studio
Gradle: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

when I do this

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" -->
    android:id="@+id/imageButton" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/gfx_select_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"/>
```

any help is appreciated, thx!

Comment: move it outside the ImageButton and try

Comment: Please post the entire XML, maybe the error is in your code rather than the comment.

Comment: @NitroNbg trust me. You can not put a comment inside a tag xml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XML comments cannot be placed inside tag markup. Move the comment for example above or below your `ImageButton` tag.

Here's the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-comments) reference, with emphasis added:

> Comments may appear anywhere in a document **outside** other **markup**

Where [markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#dt-markup) is defined as:

> Markup takes the form of start-tags, end-tags, empty-element tags, entity references, character references, comments, CDATA section delimiters, document type declarations, processing instructions, XML declarations, text declarations, and any white space that is at the top level of the document entity (that is, outside the document element and not inside any other markup)

Answer (score 4):

Its not just AS. You need to place your comments outside of your end tag `</>` so do something like

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageButton" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/gfx_select_medium"
android:layout_marginRight="22dp"/>    
<!-- android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" -->
```

See [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#sec-comments) and [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#dt-markup) from W3 about xml comments. In a nutshell, it says

> [Definition: Comments may appear anywhere in a document outside other markup;

notice

> **outside other markup**

from the first link and

> [Definition: Markup takes the form of start-tags, end-tags, ...

from the second link

Comment: so anywhere inside a layout file doesn't work because everything is inside the first level then. that's not much use!

Comment: @steveh no, they **can** be inside of a layout file as indicated in the answers. They just can't be inside of start/end tag for the other nodes. But they **can** be inside of the start/end tag of the root element.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that comments within an xml file are considered nodes of XmlComment type, so if you load the xml file those nodes are going to get loaded and it is up to you to avoid them or filter them when parsing the loaded content.

So, This will be the correct format,

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageButton" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/gfx_select_medium"
android:layout_marginRight="22dp"/>    
<!-- android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" -->
```

Or you can see this [link](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/xmlinformation/ht/htcommentxml.htm)..