# Comments in Android xml file inside component definition does not work

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

Why do I get error when I comment a line inside objects definition?:

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/optionList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/option_array"
    <!-- android:onClick="optionListClick"  -->//here is NOT fine, xml does not compile
 />
 <!-- android:onClick="optionListClick"  -->//here is fine
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comments in layout XML not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743816/comments-in-layout-xml-not-working)

Comment: See the post I linked to. It's not a well-formed xml document when you use the first comment

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you. I love Windows Phone, this is a different world.

Comment: I'm not sure what a Windows phone has to do with it. XML is XML. Anyway, you're welcome